# how to assign some vales to different variables iteratively

Tags: python, postgresql

Suppose I have a list

```
 [('maindb', 'localhost', 'postgres', 'root')]
```

and I want to assign these vales to 4 different variables iteratively, what will be the way?

I have tried

```
[db, host, user, password] = [x for x in user_list]
```

but this is not working. Error:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: `[('maindb', 'localhost', 'postgres', 'root')]` is a list. But it's a list that contains 1 item, which is a tuple of 4 strings. In general, the format is `x, y, z = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Is your list intentionally a singleton with the only element being a 4-tuple?

Comment: Also, do you know that the list will always have 4 values?

Answer (score 2):

> you should use this.

```
db, host, user, password = user_list[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite clear on what you are trying to do:

```
[x for x in user_list]
```

Is just the same as the original user_list but assuming you have a list of 4-tuples then you can do:

```
for x in user_list:
    db, host, user, password = x
    <logic>
```

Or even more concisely:

```
for db, host, user, password in user_list:
    <logic>
```

If you want named access to these values to improve readability of code then you could look at `namedtuple` and create a list of named tuples. Here's how `namedtuple`s work:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Account = namedtuple('Account', ['db', 'host', 'user', 'password'])
account = Account(user_list[0])
print(account.db, account.host, account.user, account.password)
```

And to create a list of these namedtuples:

```
accounts = [Account(x) for x in user_list]
```